# sem_timedwait Fails at Random

Tags: c++, concurrency, process, posix

I've written a small class that encapsulates shared locks and shared semaphores. These classes pass all of my unit tests, except for one: about 60% of the time locking a shared memory semaphore using sem_timedwait fails. Here's my code:

```
SharedLock::SharedLock(const SharedSemaphore& semaphore, unsigned int wait_ns) :
    Succeeded(false),
    Semaphore(semaphore)
{
    timespec wait;
    if(clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &wait) < 0)
    {
        throw exception_ty(SHARED_LOCK_RUNTIME_ERROR,
            "SharedLock::SharedLock(...) failed: clock_gettime(...) encountered an error.");
    }

    unsigned long ns = wait_ns % 1000000000;
    wait.tv_sec += (wait_ns - ns) / 1000000000;
    wait.tv_nsec += ns;
    int result = sem_timedwait(const_cast<sem_t*>(Semaphore.Semaphore.get_data()), &wait);

    if(result < 0 && errno != ETIMEDOUT)
    {
        throw_on_sem_wait();
    }

    else if(result == 0)
    {
        Succeeded = true;
    }
}
```

I am able to lock and unlock this semaphore without any errors using sem_wait and sem_trywait; only sem_timedwait fails randomly. When it fails it always sets errno to EINVAL. I am running these tests on Ubuntu Linux 12.10 (64 bit).

Could anyone suggest why I am having these problems, and how I may solve them?

Comment: Is there any chance that the parameter `semaphore`, which is passed as const reference is getting out of scope somewere else? - 
Does `SharedSemaphore::~SharedSemaphore()` destroy the underlying `sem_t` object? - 
Is `SharedLock::Semaphore` declared as `SharedSemaphore&`?

Comment: Hi Ichram, good questions: the test works sometimes, but not always. This leads me to suspect it's an environmental problem or something similar. SharedLock::Semaphore is declared as SharedSemaphore&. I'll write some additional tests and provide you with more information later tonight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`EINVAL` is returned either if sem is not a livad semaphore, or the value of abs_timeout.tv_nsecs is less than 0, or greater than or equal to 1000 million.

In your case sem should be a valid one, so the possible reason is that the `wait.tv_nsec` exceeds 1000 million, because it looks possible for the code `wait.tv_nsec += ns;` does not check the value.

You could print its value for debugging purpose, to see if it's the root cause.

Comment: Mine - I think you've found it. I haven't had a chance to test this just yet, but I would certainly say that you appear to have found a bug. I'll make the necessary correction tonight and let you know what happens.

Comment: Good and look forward to hearing feedback :)